# What happened to the world nodes?

Tags: node-editor

I am following a slightly older tutorial from 2017, where it´s about world nodes.
I can´t find them. I guess the node editor is now the shade editor.

Comment: You need to open the Shader Editor and switch it from Object to World, also enable the Use Nodes option

Comment: Now I see it, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use *Shading* workspace or just switch any area to the *Shader Editor*:

[image]

Next to area type selection, change the shader type:

[image]